# integral related to a general bivariate copula C(u,v) of |u-v|

Tags: independence, copula, integral, measure-theory

I'm trying to compute the following integral over the unit square $I^2=[0,1]^2$:
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1 |u-v|dC(u,v),
$$
where $C(u,v)$ is a generic bivariate copula, which should be equal to
$$
1-2\int_0^1 C(u,u)du
$$
(see the paper https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.2478/demo-2014-0004/html).
I've tried to split the integral into two parts, where $u\geq v$ and $u<v$, but I don't know how to proceed further.